# VSCode doesn't show poetry virtualenvs in select interpreter option

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-poetry

I need help. VSCode will NEVER find poetry virtualenv interpreter no matter what I try.

Installed poetry Python package manager using a standard `$ curl` method as explained [in the official documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation).

Started a project by `$ poetry new finance-essentials_37-64`, installed poetry environment with `$ poetry install`.

So now I can see that I indeed have a virtual environment by:

```
Jaepil@Jaepil-PC MINGW64 /e/VSCodeProjects/finance_essentials_37-64 $ poetry env list 
>> finance-essentials-37-64-SCQrHB_N-py3.7 (Activated)
```

and this virtualenv is installed at: `C:\Users\Jaepil\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs`, which has `finance-essentials-37-64-SCQrHB_N-py3.7` directory.

However, VSCode is unable to find this virtualenv in its 'select interpreter' command. I only see a bunch of Anaconda and Pipenv environments but not the poetry environment's interpreter that I've just made.

I also added `"python.venvPath": "~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs",` to my `settings.json` as suggested in [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8372#issuecomment-556984062), but to no avail. 
Still doesn't work.

I also tried an absolute path, by adding `"python.venvPath": "C:\\Users\\Jaepil\\AppData\\Local\\pypoetry\\Cache\\virtualenvs",` to the same settings, but it also doesn't work.

[VSCode settings reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference) states that it has `python.poetryPath` as a default but it doesn't seem to work either. Should I change the default value `"poetry"` in this case?

> python.poetryPath
>
> "poetry"
>
> Specifies the location of the Poetry dependency manager executable, if
>   installed. The default value "poetry" assumes the executable is in the
>   current path. The Python extension uses this setting to install
>   packages when Poetry is available and there's a poetry.lock file in
>   the workspace folder.

I'm on Windows 10 pro 64bit & Has Python 3.7.6 installed on the system.

```
PS C:\Users\Jaepil> python
Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Answer (score 423, accepted):

You just need to type in your shell:

```bash
poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
```

The virtualenv will be created inside the project path and vscode will recognize.

---

If you already have created your project, you need to re-create the virtualenv to make it appear in the correct place:

```bash
poetry env list  # shows the name of the current environment
poetry env remove <current environment>
poetry install  # will create a new environment using your updated configuration
```

Comment: Actually this is quite good I like to keep my venv in the same place as project

Comment: yes I also prefer keeping my venv inside the project root @mrWiecek

Comment: Unfortunately, when using the fish shell, `poetry shell` breaks when there are spaces in the complete path name. If you are working in a directory with *any* spaces in any *any* ancestor director, then poetry will fail to work.

Comment: @BallpointBen I have a poetry project located in C:\Programming\project with no spaces, but my user account directory (including the cache directory where the virtualenvs are normally stored) does have a space in the name. Also, after I ran this command, it did not move anything around. Do I need to do this from a scratch project?

Comment: @Goodies yes, this only affects future environments, not existing ones. I’m not sure whether spaces are permissible for you; my only experience was with fish shell on a Mac.

Comment: Understood. I was able to run `poetry env remove [existing environmet]` and then when I built it the next time, it built the new env in the correct location. Thank you!

Comment: this doesn't work out-of-the-box if the project root contains multiple 'sub-projects'. In machine learning, it is common to have ```training``` and ```serving``` sub-directories. I have made this technique work by adding ```./training/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages``` (same for serving) into ```python.analysis.extraPaths``` in VSCode ```settings.json```. Is there a better way?

Comment: If you allow spaces in your file path, you deserve the pain you experience. UNIX 101.

Comment: When you do this, don't forget to add `${wordspaceFolder}` to vscode's Python: Venv Folders setting. Open settings (ctrl + , ) and type 'venv' to find this option. Click "Add Item" and type `${wordspaceFolder}`

Comment: Wanted to add that I had to reload the vscode window then select interpreter after doing this. Otherwise, vscode would not find python in `.venv` for some reason.

Comment: @JoeSadoski what OS?

Comment: @ChristianH This was on macOS 11.6

Comment: Strange, usually only reloading does it.

Comment: I applied this answer to an existing project and ran into `CalledProcessError`  and `EnvCommandError`. I solved the errors by copying `pyvenv.cfg` from the directory where the existing environment was located into the root directory of my project. Then I ran `poetry install` and it worked.

Comment: Additionally, you can make sure all developers are using this config in that project by: `poetry config --local virtualenvs.in-project true`

Comment: @pinkspikyhairman might try to use a `workspace` to add those sub proj folders

Answer (score 59):

You need to set `"python.venvPath": "C:\\Users\\Jaepil\\AppData\\Local\\pypoetry\\Cache\\virtualenvs"` in your settings (the one you tried is for UNIX).

You can also  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8372 to help prioritize adding Poetry virtual environment support to the Python extension.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like that's the only way as of now.

Comment: There is another way :)

Comment: update from 2022, `"python.venvPath":` is no more available in vscode

Comment: Ubuntu paths: ls ~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/

Comment: This was the only answer that worked for me on Win10.

Answer (score 14):

You can add your virtualenvs folder to `"python.venvFolders"` in vs code global settings.

Like that for Windows:

```json
"python.venvFolders": [
    "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\pypoetry\\Cache\\virtualenvs\\"
  ]
```

to get the path you run `poetry config virtualenvs.path` as @Aipi has commented

Comment: Linux: `~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs`

Comment: To show path: `poetry config virtualenvs.path`

Comment: this is "the answer" as of 2023

Answer (score 14):

The settings have changed for the Python extension in VS Code. I was able to select my Poetry virtual environment for my interpreter/ipynb kernel again after changing the dated `python.pythonPath` setting (yours might be `python.venvPath`) to `python.defaultInterpreterPath` in the VS Code settings.json file.

Note: My work computer is a Mac but I expect this should work for Windows. To find the ~path, enter `poetry env info --path` in your CLI under the appropriate project folder, then tack on the subdirectory info where Python is installed. On MacOS/Linux, this ends with "/bin/python"; on Windows, "python.exe". https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter for more info.

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/Users/myname/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/projectname-randomnumbers-py3.9/bin/python",
}
```