# How do I make Poetry site-packages searchable on VSCode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-poetry

VSCode supports many virtual environments as default and those environments' files are searchable. However, I'm using [Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) and its libraries don't seem to come up on the search.

I manually set my Python interpreter by changing `.vscode/settings.json` in my project directory. (Because command palette's `Python: Select interpreter` didn't work either.

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "~\\AppData\\Local\\pypoetry\\Cache\\virtualenvs\\finance-essentials-37-64-58e2e1Bc-py3.7\\Scripts"
}
```

I want to make files in `~\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\finance-essentials-37-64-58e2e1Bc-py3.7\Lib\site-packages` searchable on my command pelette & code context so that I can look up library sources easily.

How do I do this?

Comment: You might want to ask on Poetry's repo too. https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues

Comment: @AKX Right, but Poetry issue rules state that I should ask tips & tricks on SO. "For support questions, please post on StackOverflow."

Comment: Answered on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882884/vscode-doesnt-show-poetry-virtualenvs-in-select-interpreter-option/64434542#64434542

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I like this question, actually. Being able to search and look through packages easily makes one more productive.

There's a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30234987/3385948).

VS Code multi-root workspaces explained in-depth [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces), as fellow [*snarky*](https://snarky.ca/) Canadian @BrettCannon [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60067509/3385948).

In VS Code, you just need to click on `File -> Add Folder to Workspace...` and locate your Poetry virtual environment, or wherever your `site-packages` folder is, which contains your externally-installed libraries/packages.

Or... to do the exact-same-thing as above the hard way... Just create a JSON-based `workspace.code-workspace` file in your `.vscode` directory, alongside your `launch.json` and `settings.json` files. This will load your multi-root workspace automatically when you reload VS Code. Then paste in the following contents, changing the second `path` as required for your own `site-packages` folder:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": ".."
        },
        {
            "path": "../../usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages"
        }
    ],
    "settings": {}
}
```

Comment: is there a way to use env variable in workspace definition? like `"path": "$VIRTUAL_ENV"`?

Comment: actually here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables; I understood that "/${env:VIRTUAL_ENV}" should work but it doesn't. when I "copy path", it returns this exact string without interpolation

Answer (score -2):

You could use a multi-root workspace that includes your code and the `site-packages` directory.

Although I would ask why you feel the need to have installed 3rd-party code searchable in that way? General code navigation from within the Python extension should help you discover details of the code you're using and documentation should be the primary way to learn about the code you're using.