# VSCode doesn't show poetry virtualenvs

Tags: visual-studio-code, python-poetry

VSCode wouldn't show venvs created with poetry in "change kernel" window.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882884/vscode-doesnt-show-poetry-virtualenvs-in-select-interpreter-option) thread but it didn't work. As well as the topic being 2 years old.
Eventhough I would like to avoid installing all the dependencies in local folder for each project (one of the suggested answers), I still tried it but VSCode doesn't see it either (.venv folder created inside the project).

Right now poetry saves all the venvs in: `~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs` after `poetry shell` any of the venvs. I added it to settings.json with

```
"python.venvPath": "/home/gobsan/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs",
"python.venvFolders": [
    "/home/gobsan/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs"
  ],
```

2x times just in case, but it is greyed out and doesn't seem to work.

I have also tried to change `poetry config virtualenvs.path` to
`~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv/bin`
`~/.local/share/pypoetry/venv`
`~/.local/share/pypoetry`

hoping VSCode will see it since it can see something there
[image]

My main goal is to be able to see and switch between different venvs inside Jupyter. Switching poetry venvs for python scripts is no problem.
Thank you for any help.

ps. working through wsl2

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/59882884/968003?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should end your path with a forward slash, like `"/home/gobsan/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/"`.
I was just researching Poetry and VSCode and ended up doing this as well.

Here's [my own path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFGP8.png) and [what my interpreter looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s6sB.png) after the settings update

Answer (score 2):

The settings have changed for the Python extension in VS Code. I was able to select my Poetry virtual environment for my interpreter/ipynb kernel again after changing the dated `python.pythonPath` setting (yours might be `python.venvPath`) to `python.defaultInterpreterPath` in the VS Code settings.json file.

I don't know if changing this setting will allow VS Code to automatically pick up other Poetry virtual environment options listed under `poetry env info --path` in your CLI. The guidance here will hopefully be of use for that: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_manually-specify-an-interpreter

```
{
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "/Users/myname/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/projectname-randomnumbers-py3.9/bin/python",
}
```

(my work computer is a Mac)

Answer (score 1):

Add `poetry.toml` to your project root with content:

```
[virtualenvs]
create = true
in-project = true
```

This will create the virtual environment in your project root instead of `~/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs` (mac):

```
$ poetry shell
```

Install the dependencies:

```
$ poetry install
```

Now, selecting the kernel, you will find your poetry virtual environment in the project root as `.venv`.

Comment: does not work for me: `poetry` ignores the `[virtualenvs]` entry.

Comment: Note that this is **not** `pyproject.toml`.